# keep the variable constant in loop when the variable is reused in python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to loop through the JSON where I have `sid` which is initially zero when it is passed through the Stored Procedure it will return some value `8463` and I want to keep this value as `sid` and again I want to pass the same value which is `8463` through the SP again.

I have tried keeping it constant but once it loop through the one dictionary it automatically increasing the value of `sid` Any help would be appreciated

Views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def SaveUserResponse(request):
  if request.method == 'POST': 
       for ran in request.data:

            print(type(ran),'QId--',ran.get('QId'), ran)
            print(type(request.data))
            auditorid =ran.get('AuditorId')
            print('SaveUserResponse auditorid---', auditorid)
            ticketid = ran.get('TicketId')
            qid = ran.get('QId')
            answer = ran.get('Answer')
            sid = '0'
            
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_SaveAuditResponse] @auditorid=%s,@ticketid=%s,@qid=%s,@answer=%s,@sid=%s',
                                            (auditorid,ticketid,qid,answer, sid))
            
            result_st = cursor.fetchall()
            print('sp_SaveAuditResponse', result_st)

                    #     # if qid != 1 or qid != 42:     
        for row in result_st:
                print('sp_SaveAuditResponse', row)
                sid = row[0]
        return Response(row[0])
```

Payload:

```
    [{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":42,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 
    
{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":43,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""},  

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":44,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":45,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":46,"Answer":"3","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 
{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":47,"Answer":"5","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":48,"Answer":"5","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":49,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":50,"Answer":"5","SID":"0","Comments":""}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed by initialising the `sid` before the loop and just return the `sid` after the loop. Here is the code

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def SaveUserResponse(request):
  if request.method == 'POST': 

       sid = 0
       for ran in request.data:

            print(type(ran),'QId--',ran.get('QId'), ran)
            print(type(request.data))
            auditorid =ran.get('AuditorId')
            print('SaveUserResponse auditorid---', auditorid)
            ticketid = ran.get('TicketId')
            qid = ran.get('QId')
            answer = ran.get('Answer')

            cursor = connection.cursor()

            cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_SaveAuditResponse] @auditorid=%s,@ticketid=%s,@qid=%s,@answer=%s,@sid=%s',
                                            (auditorid,ticketid,qid,answer, sid))

            result_st = cursor.fetchall()
            print('sp_SaveAuditResponse', result_st)

           for row in result_st:
                print('sp_SaveAuditResponse', row)
                sid = row[0]
        return sid
```